# Spark Dataframe combine json key value in one row - Scala or Python

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am querying spark sql like below and trying to combine the columns in one row :

```
interalexternalid = spark.sql("""Select InternalId, ExternalId from datatable limit 4""")

jsonDf = interalexternalid.select(to_json(struct([interalexternalid[x] for x in interalexternalid.columns])).alias("body"))
display(jsonDf)
```

I am getting the data like this:

```
"body"
{"InternalId":480941,"ExternalId":"a020H00001Tt7NrQAJ"}
{"InternalId":480942,"ExternalId":"a020H00001Tt7NsQAJ"}
{"InternalId":480556,"ExternalId":"a020H00001TdAEVQA3"}
{"InternalId":480557,"ExternalId":"a020H00001TdAEWQA3"}
```

My objective is to get the data like below in "body" column

"body":

```
 [{"InternalId": 480941}, {"ExternalId": "a020H00001Tt7NrQAJ"}]
 [{"InternalId": 480942}, {"ExternalId": "a020H00001Tt7NsQAJ"}]
 [{"InternalId": 480556}, {"ExternalId": "a020H00001TdAEVQA3"}]
 [{"InternalId": 480557}, {"ExternalId": "a020H00001TdAEWQA3"}]
```

how can this be achieved . I am using python in above context . but both python and scala solution would be helpful .
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `struct` use `array` method since you need `body` as an array. And use `create_map` to create Map from column name to value:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, lit, col, to_json, create_map

df.select(to_json(
    array(*[create_map(lit(c), col(c)) for c in df.columns])
).alias("body")).show(truncate=False)

+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|body                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"InternalId":"480941"},{"ExternalId":"a020H00001Tt7NrQAJ"}]|
|[{"InternalId":"480942"},{"ExternalId":"a020H00001Tt7NsQAJ"}]|
|[{"InternalId":"480556"},{"ExternalId":"a020H00001TdAEVQA3"}]|
|[{"InternalId":"480557"},{"ExternalId":"a020H00001TdAEWQA3"}]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```